# Varnish Turpentine - Can you add ESI cache policies to a template file?

Tags: varnish, turpentine

Is it possible to add ESI cache policies to a Magento phtml template file?

To expand on why I ask, on our store we're using the [VS_Ajax module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vs-ajax-add-to-cart-add-to-wishlist-add-to-compare-paging-toolbar.html) which doesn't play nice with turpentine.

With this module the mark up for the add to wishlist button on the product and category listings page is changed, and has a different form key depending on the users logged in.  If varnish cache's the page before a user logs in, a logged in customer will be instructed to that they need to  log in before they add a product to the wish list, or vice versa.

For instnace the mark up with the Ajax wishlist turned on is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ajaxWishlist("http://our-domain.com/wishlist/index/add/product/242/form_key/WXLqGQuMFGOglelc/","242";);return false;" class="link-wishlist">
```

And with it turned off, it's:

```
<a href="http://our-domain.com/wishlist/index/add/product/413/form_key/LNjeYewcIfZ5ZvYi/" class="link-wishlist">
```

The PHP responsible for this code is:

```
<?php $i=1; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <!--  CODE OMMITED FOR BREVITY  -->
    <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('ajax/wishlistcompare/enabledpro')){?>
        <ul class="add-to-links">
            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() and $wishlist) : ?>
                <li><a href="#" onclick='ajaxWishlist("<?php echo str_replace($http[0], $http[1], $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product)); ?>","<?php echo $_product->getId()?>");return false;' class="link-wishlist"><?php echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsBlacknwhite')->getIcon('wishlist'); ?><span id='ajax_wishlist_loading<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' class="ajax-loader-item" style='display:none'><img src='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif')?>' alt="" /></span></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) and $compareproducts): ?>
                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="#" onclick='ajaxCompare("<?php echo str_replace($http[0], $http[1], $_compareUrl); ?>","<?php echo $_product->getId()?>");return false;' class="link-compare"><?php echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsBlacknwhite')->getIcon('compare'); ?><span id='ajax_loading<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' class="ajax-loader-item" style='display:none'><img src='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif')?>' alt="" /></span></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php }else{?>
        <ul class="add-to-links">
            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() and $wishlist) : ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsBlacknwhite')->getIcon('wishlist'); ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) and $compareproducts): ?>
                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo MAGE::helper('ThemeOptionsBlacknwhite')->getIcon('compare'); ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php } ?>
    <!--  CODE OMMITED FOR BREVITY  -->
<?php $i++; endforeach ?>
```

I tried putting this PHP into a `block` with a layout update with the esi caching policy:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <block type='catalog/product_list' name='wishlist_compare' template='ajax/catalog/wishlist-compare.phtml'>
                <action method="setEsiOptions">
                    <params>
                        <access>private</access>
                    </params>
                </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

But this wouldn't work as the PHP code is in a loop `foreach` so I can't grab data such as `$_product` in my new `wishlist_compare` block.

It would be much easier if I could just add the ESI cache policy to the template?  Is this possible?  Perhaps it would make no difference. Would it work as the php code in question is in a `foreach` loop, can varnish handle that?

Any other solutions welcome.

Comment: Does your new block inherity from the Mage_Core_Block_Template class?  Turpentine's ESI policies only apply to blocks that inherit from that class (source: https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/ESI_Cache_Policy).  The next thing to check is enable debug info and block logging in the admin panel Varnish options (System->Configuration->Varnish Options), load your page, and then check your install's system.log to see if you can find you block listed.  That'll give you a clue as to whether or not Turpentine is considering your custom block for caching.

Comment: Something else I just came across that might help you is this post: https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/74.  The specific message is from Aheadley where he says " since the block is defined in local.xml it doesn't exist when Turpentine's layout XML files are run, because the local.xml file is handled last. Try moving the ESI policies to local.xml (after the block definitions), then flush the cache."

Comment: Thanks @MikeLevy, although the issue is really, I can't put the code I wish to in a block as it is in the `$_productCollection` loop, so regardless of getting the esi policy on the block the php code won't work as it needs to be part of that loop, which is why I'm wondering if I can create an ESI policy directly in a phtml template file.

Comment: @MikeLevy, I'm wondering if this would make any difference after all. If it is possible to set an esi policy in the template file would it work as the php code in question is in a foreach loop, can varnish handle that?

Comment: @Holly : did you found a solution regarding adding ESI policy within the PHTML file? I encounter a similar issue while trying to adding ESI to a block created dynamically (autocomplete search block into header). I would really appreciate your feedback.